# Magento Category Movement

Tags: magento-1.8, category, migration

All the new category changes are done on staging server, and now i wanted to move it to live. I cannot move complete database, since both the database are not synchronized and i don't want to loss sales/order/customer data.

If i only move table that are specific to category, will this work without any issue? I also wanted to retain category ID after moving it to production server.

Can anyone please guide which all table i need to move to make this category migration successful.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just export all tables starting `catalog_` (check 'disable foreign key checks' and 'add drop tables if exist') in database and import into the other database. This will ensure the necessary relationships between products and categories still remain intact (to clarify, this will import all products and what categories they are assigned to etc).

This then won't touch sales/orders/customers etc but just import everything related to the catalog.

You may find [this](http://webexplorar.com/magento-import-and-export-all-productscategories-and-images-using-csv-file/) useful as well.

Comment: but product tables start with `catalog_`. And the OP does not want to move them...I think.

Comment: Yeh, mentioned that in my answer - this will only work if it is ONLY the customers/sales/orders he doesn't want to touch of course.

Comment: Thank you guys for your immediate answer. I will definitely try this.

Comment: If i move all table starting with catalog_category, will this work? I have Flat Catalog enabled. I don't want to touch product tables if its possible.

Comment: Do i also need to move Index tables?

Comment: Ah if you don't want to touch the products then it's probably best to create a dataflow import or consider [an extension](http://www.magentoworks.net/importexport-magento-category-extension) for this. Trying to move the categories alone in the database directly will probably screw a few things up somewhere.

Comment: I did it. I just move all table  ( Catalog_category_*) except index table, And it worked good for me.

Comment: Great stuff, glad it worked out. I'd recommend carrying out some extensive testing just to be sure that nothing broke in the process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15054/discussion-between-trimantra-software-solution-and-zigojacko).